# How to resize child of RelativeLayout when making another child visible?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

When I call view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) on the RelativeLayout @+id/saveCancelBar below, it covers part of the FrameLayout. I would like the FrameLayout to shrink to fit the RelativeLayout. If I put everything in a LinearLayout rather than a RelativeLayout, showing the SaveCancelBar simply shifts everything upwards and moves part of the Toolbar off screen

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center|bottom">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view_panes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/listContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/content_view_panes"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/saveCancelBar">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editorCancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/editor_cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editorSaveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/editor_save"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do two things.

Firstly, the FrameLayout with id `listContainer` will not shirk vertically because it's parent has `layout_height` set to `match_parent`. You should wrap the parent `content_view_panes` and the `saveCancelBar` in a LinearLayout with vertical orientation, and set the `layout_height` to `0dp`, with `layout_width` set to `1`. For a child of a LinearLayout, this tells it to fill up the remaining space. You don't need to alter the width or height of `listContainer` as it will resize based on it's parent.

Now when you change the visibility of `saveCancelBar` the `content_view_panes`, and thus `listContainer`, will have their height adjusted.

E.g.:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/content_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center|bottom">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view_panes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/listContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/content_view_panes"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/saveCancelBar">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editorCancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/editor_cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editorSaveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/editor_save"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this isn't working. Does it matter when I set the visibility? I assume it should be in onCreateView()? Does it matter that the height of the LinearLayout with id `content_view_panes` is set to match_parent? If I go for wrap_content it gives me an error about putting a WebView in a parent with height wrap_content.

Comment: My mistake, I hadn't noticed that the LinearLayout `content_view_panes` is horizontal orientation. I've updated the answer and added working, tested code